# Change Path for Zend projects

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, url-rewriting

I am new to `ZF` and using `netbeans IDE` to create zend projects. When i am running this project its opens a `"Index of /ZendProject1"` with directories and when i click on the folder "public" then i will get what i written under `"applicationiews\scripts\index\index.phtml"`.

I want my Zend projects to be accessible via `http://localhost/ZendProject1/` and not with this --> `http://localhost/ZendProject1/public/`.

What settings do i need to change for zend folder..as im currently have many projects under my htdocs so it would not be a reasonable solution to change from httpd.conf settings. I think there must be some setting to be managed although i googled it but no solution :(

> Note -- I am on Zend learning mode so kindly suggest me some links
>   where i can found more tutorials on zend apart from
>   http://devzone.zend.com/ and
>   http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Zend-Framework-Basic-Tutorial-P840.html.
>   (familiar with PHP and understand the basic concept of MVC design
>   pattern ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.htaccess` file to each of your project`s directory (root directory of the project, not public). It should contain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled on your server? What do you get in your browser?

Comment: I pasted this code in .htaccess file under htdocs\ZendProject1  and this is what im getting when trying to run it in browser -- http://localhost/zendproject1/  ----->ERROR An error occurred
Page not found

Comment: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so this is uncommented

Comment: As i can see your server is configured with DocumentRoot set to one folder where you hold your projects. Its best to define single virtual host each project you have. For example ZendProject1.localhost.

Comment: is virtual host can be managed under zend project folder as i guess if its a shared host provider we may face problem..its better if u edit the answer..as im very poor with rewrite rules so u have 2 help me :)

Comment: .htaccess is not working because you have `AllowOverride None` for project folder. It should be `AllowOverride All`. All is about server config now.